# Http/Smtp MIME multipart. Why boundary?

Tags: http, smtp, multipart, boundary, content-length

I have a question regarding the design of these protocols. Why do we use boundary to separate parts of the multipart message instead of introducing a content-length for each part? Using length the parsing would easier. Do I miss some principal reason for using boundaries and not length parameter? Thanks!

Comment: @VariabileAleatoria I think that Steffen's answer is what you're looking for.  It's one of those things that has been carried over from the past, and is used in a lot of different contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using length the parsing would [be] easier

This is where you are wrong. The authors of multipart MIME had cases in mind where you could not determine beforehand the length of a message part. Think of content encodings that alter message lengths such as base64, UUencode and others. There's also compression, encryption and whatnot. Also: `Content-Length` is an entity header. This means if you reach it, you've already begun to parse a message part. It comes with literally no advantage over a boundary marker.

If you study older protocols, you will often encounter some marker (usually `\0`) to indicate the end of a message. Sending the byte count of a message is another solution, but you won't find it a lot in places where message content has to be converted on-the-fly or is to be streamed in some fashion.

Bottom line: The multipart boundary allows some interesting applications with message contents of unpredictable size. [HTTP server pushing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push) is a notable example.

Comment: But it depends on how you define the content-length. You can always use it asthe number of bytes actually sent in the current part (after encoding and/or compressing). In this case you always know when the part is finished by just counting instead of pattern matching. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. You cannot do this if e.g. you are generating the message content dynamically or if you are confined resource-wise in a fashion that does not allow to process a message part as whole. To stay in nowadays standards, imagine multi-gigabyte-sized messages. Btw: the `Content-Length` header is defined exactly as you wrote here.

Comment: Yes, with prefixing each data chunk with the length and then marking the last data chunk in a special way you can transfer data without upfront knowing the total size. It's much easier to parse than multipart MIME. This is done in HTTP chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: Thank you, DeSourcerer. I agree that for on the fly message generation it would't work. But the only practical example that I see is streaming. While for sending huge files you still can use file size instead of a boundary, no? You don't need any extra resource to get the file size before generating the http message.

Comment: Steffen, thanks! Http chunked transfer is very helpful in explaining the issue.

Comment: @Michael think in more general terms. It is not always possible to determine the size of files as well. Think of remote resources for example. Having said that, keep in mind multipart MIME is a general-purpose thing. I think the boundary is actually a decent solution for that.

Comment: If the content is not known beforehand, how does the sender make sure that the boundary does not occur in the payload?

Comment: @xmjx That is actually something that should never happen. However, consider that the boundary is not on its own; it is surrounded by syntactically relevant linebreaks: `\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n`. This still does not *ensure* a valid boundary won't be part of a message body. But at least it's unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Because in good old days the MIME Standard was defined this way.
One of the reasons was probably that content-length has a problem with text/plain data, where the newline might be either CR (old mac), LF (unix) or CR LF (windows, dos). The other might be that it is easier for a human to read, which is IMHO a bad argument but happens a lot when preferring textual representations like HTTP, XML or  SOAP instead of the more effective binary ways like ASN.1 or SUN RPC.

You might also view it as a successful attempt of the industry to sell more powerful servers by introducing useless overhead into the protocols :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan! Just a follow up question. You mention the possible priblem with the end of line symbol. But why? Content-length will just count the actual symbols (cr o cr+lf). Why it can introduce a problem while parsing?

Comment: because MTA (mail transfer agents) and MUA (mail user agents, e.g. the mail client) are free to change the message, as long as the contents does not change. Like if an MTA does not understand Content-Transfer-Encoding binary the sending MUA/MTA will transform it to base64. Also, text/plain data attached on a windows platform (line ending CR LF) will be automatically transformed to line ending LF if read/saved on a unix platform. While this might look like a good idea in theory in reality it gives lots of problems, because lots of MUA set a content-type of text/plain even for binary content :(

Comment: But as I understand, the content-length is the number of bytes and it does not depend on encoding. So if MTA/MUA change the message it will also update the content-length field. No?

Comment: There is no content-length header defined for MIME, even if some MUA add it (but usually only the MUA of the final recipient to ease parsing of stored messages). With MIME the length of each part is solely defined by the boundaries.
This is different with HTTP, which uses lots of ideas from MIME. Here Content-Length is used to describe the total length of the body. Recoding of the content is usually not done (HTTP considers content as binary for transfer, whereas old SMTP considers content as text) and if a web proxy changes the content it has to adjust the content-length.

Comment: Yes, in HTTP Post request, we use content length for the whole message body size and boundaries to separate parts. So, to summarize, conceptually we could use with no problem a design in which we don't use boundaries but use content-length measured in bytes for each part of the multipart message. Correct?

Comment: "in HTTP Post request, we use content length for the whole message body size" That is actually a "best" practice and in no way a must. If you study RFC 2616, you will find that all parties are required to understand chunked encoding. Thus you could technically send a POST request chunk encoded without message size. However, server support for this is slim, so sending the message size is the preferred method.

Comment: In theory you could send within a POST or PUT request whatever you want, as long as the content length is known to the server by setting either the content-length header or using chunked transfer encoding. If you have multiple parts within the same POST you could pack them like you want, e.g. as multipart MIME, json, ZIP, XML ..., as long the server will understand it. HTML forms will be transfered as MIME multipart by the browser, but with your own ajax calls you can use whatever you want.

Comment: Hm, I beg to differ. The server's responsibility end when the transfer encoding has been stripped and the message body has been passed to the webapplication. Parsing the message body is already the webapp's duty IMHO. Btw: multipart messages are only relevant in HTML forms if they carry any files. Everything else should be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the way compacter format ;)

Comment: I aggree with you. Nevertheless there would be easier to parse and more efficient ways to separate the parts in the message body from each other (and I don't mean XML, which is even worse).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what [DaSourcerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3012385/dasourcerer) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20936056/1082681), I want to point out that there are many valid reasons why one would not know the content length. In a comment, the most compelling one was named already: **streaming.**

Stop thinking "file size" or even "file" at all, folks! When a MIME multipart is being constructed, the creator might not even read files but input streams, or she might read from a platform-dependent reader line by line, which introduces the LF vs. CRLF problem again. The stream might be so big, it would be inefficient or even impossible to fully read it before writing it out again, just to determine its size.

Last but not least, [RFC 1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) specifies that a multipart entity can have a preamble (stuff before the first boundary) and an epilogue (stuff after the last boundary). Quote:

```
From: Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com> 
To:  Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com> 
Subject: Sample message 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="simple 
boundary" 

This is the preamble.  It is to be ignored, though it 
is a handy place for mail composers to include an 
explanatory note to non-MIME compliant readers. 
--simple boundary 

This is implicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
It does NOT end with a linebreak. 
--simple boundary 
Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 

This is explicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
It DOES end with a linebreak. 

--simple boundary-- 
This is the epilogue.  It is also to be ignored.
```